What is this around this ceiling light?
Things that have recently been performed in this area:

removal of popcorn ceiling
installation of ceiling light

The area directly above this on the roof does not seem obviously in poor repair.
Any thoughts?


These are water stains. Remove the light and confirm.

Or this? How can I tell if stains are caused by a ceiling that is drying out, or if there is still a leak?

Or this? How should I go about troubleshooting this brown spot that appeared on my master bathroom ceiling?

Water coming through roof leaks can travel quite some distance before hitting your ceiling.
